# Is there a way to expire value in Neo4j, and change it to default one

Tags: graph, nosql, neo4j

We are building small social network, with friend connections and presences. We are planning to implement friend connections using Neo4J. And we already have infrastructure for presence management, implemented using expiration keys in Redis (If there is no key that means a user is offline, otherwise he is considered online).

Most likely after getting friend connections, user will try to get presences, so the question is.

***Is there a way to implement an automatic, value change in Neo4J node?***

In our case the purpose is to replace Redis presence, with Neo4J stored data, to minimize Requests to the server, and extra querying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now there is no such mechanism but should be pretty simple to implement in a server extension or kernel-extension.

You would use a transaction-event-lister to see property changes and add those keys to a timeout-expiry map (or index) which is then regularly checked.

But it would require some java-coding or reaching out to the Neo4j community for help or Neo Technology for consulting.